# passing parameters from javascript to gwt?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am new to Gwt,i m implementing a webclipper project so my task to send some parameters from javascript file to  Gwt so that i will be able to make the connection with my couchdb database but i am getting a problem in passing parameters like title, url ,and summary from webpage to Gwt n then couchdb.The following code is my javascript code:-

```
function onPageInfo(o)  { 
    document.getElementById('title').value = o.title;         
    document.getElementById('url').value = o.url; 
    document.getElementById('summary').innerText = o.summary; 
}  

    // Global reference to the status display SPAN
    var statusDisplay = null;

    // POST the data to the server using XMLHttpRequest
    function addBookmark() {
    // Cancel the form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // The URL to POST our data to
    var postUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/practice.html?      gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997/?title=1&url=2&summary=3";

    // Set up an asynchronous AJAX POST request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', postUrl, true);

    // Prepare the data to be POSTed
    var title = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('title').value);
    var url = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('url').value);
    var summary = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('summary').value);
    var tags = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('tags').value);

    var params = 'title=' + title + 
             '&url=' + url + 
             '&summary=' + summary +
             '&tags=' + tags;

    // Replace any instances of the URLEncoded space char with +
    params = params.replace(/%20/g, '+');

    // Set correct header for form data 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

    // Handle request state change events
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    // If the request completed
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        statusDisplay.innerHTML = '';
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            // If it was a success, close the popup after a short delay
            statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Saved!';
            window.setTimeout(window.close, 1000);
        } else {// Show what went wrong
            statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Error saving: ' + xhr.statusText;
        }
    }
   };

    // Send the request and set status

    xhr.send(params);
    statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Saving...';
    }

    // When the popup HTML has loaded
    window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
    // Handle the bookmark form submit event with our addBookmark function
    document.getElementById('addbookmark').addEventListener('submit', addBookmark);


    // Cache a reference to the status display SPAN
    statusDisplay = document.getElementById('status-display');
    // Call the getPageInfo function in the background page, injecting content_script.js 


   // into the current HTML page and passing in our onPageInfo function as the callback
   chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().getPageInfo(onPageInfo);
 });
```

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function defined in a java file (of GWT client module) by exporting that function. Let's assume there is a class A.java which is also your entry point class. This class contains someMethod() which you need to call from javascript passing some parameters. The content of your class A would be something like

```
public class A implements EntryPoint {
        public static functionExported = false;
        public void onModuleLoad() {
            ExportToBeCalledFromJs();

            // other code goes here
        }

    public static native void ExportToBeCalledFromJs() /*-{
        $wnd.toBeCalledFromJs = $entry(function(s1, s2) {
            return @com.practice.gwt.client.A::someFunction();
        });
        @com.practice.gwt.client.A:functionExported = true;
        }-*/;
    }
```

Above code exports the function and makes it available to javascript. You can simply call toBeCalledFromJs(param1, param2) fromyour js where param1 would substitute s1 and param2 would substitute s2. If you wish to add more parameters you can modify $entry(function(s1, s2) in the code above.

Comment: sir, what is this functionExported ?

Comment: sry, I just typed the code without executing. It's a boolean value. It's value is changed to true after function is exported